# WP - how to remove underline in hyperlinkButton programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have developed an hyperlinkButton in C#. The underline in hyperlinkButton irritates me. I don't know how to remove it. Help me to remove the underline and i need answer in C#. [It's an WP8 app]

```
    HyperlinkButton hyperlinkButton = new HyperlinkButton()
    {
        Content = "Click me",
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        NavigateUri = new Uri("http://my-link-com", UriKind.Absolute)
    };
```

Comment: Could you post the code result you are getting?

Comment: I don't know a way that c# can do this, but CSS can!

Comment: What style are you applying to it?

Comment: @nilesh its an WP8 app

Comment: @RobertKenny its an WP8 app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know another way but setting the ControlTemplate in XAML. But you can use it in C#:

```
var str =   "<ControlTemplate TargetType=\"HyperlinkButton\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" +
            "   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment=\"{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}\" Text=\"{TemplateBinding Content}\" VerticalAlignment=\"{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}\"/>" +
            "</ControlTemplate>";

var template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(str);  

HyperlinkButton hyperlinkButton = new HyperlinkButton()
{
    Content = "Click me",
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    NavigateUri = new Uri("http://my-link-com", UriKind.Absolute),
    Template = template
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `HyperlinkButton1.Template = template;` where should i put this ?

Answer (score 6):

To quote [Douglas Stockwell](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea7f8fec-bc68-4300-bea0-60c7ee787318/how-to-remove-underline-from-hyperlink-and-change-the-color-of-the-link)

You can set properties directly, or use a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateBlue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SteelBlue" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This answer in XAML. I need answer in C#

Comment: @user2655873 I'm not sure of the c# syntax, but you should be able to find a `TextBlock` or `TextDecorations` property of your object.