# Remove underline from Hyperlink in windows phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

How to Remove Under line in hyperlink in windows phone 8.1. I don't see any solutions yet. Please help. There is not option for text decorations.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to use Hyperlink, but maybe you can use HyperlinkButton and custom it :

Take a look at this conversation : [WP - how to remove underline in hyperlinkButton programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403999/wp-how-to-remove-underline-in-hyperlinkbutton-programmatically)

There is 2 solutions : 
Set template in C# :

```
var str =   "<ControlTemplate TargetType=\"HyperlinkButton\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" +
            "   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment=\"{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}\" Text=\"{TemplateBinding Content}\" VerticalAlignment=\"{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}\"/>" +
            "</ControlTemplate>";

var template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(str);  

HyperlinkButton hyperlinkButton = new HyperlinkButton()
{
    Content = "Click me",
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    NavigateUri = new Uri("http://my-link-com", UriKind.Absolute),
    Template = template
};
```

Or use a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateBlue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SteelBlue" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

**EDIT :** I found this article about removing underline to hyperlink :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970059(v=vs.110).aspx

You can set TextDecorations property to none and remove this underline

```
<!-- Hyperlink with no underline. -->
<Hyperlink Name="myHyperlink" TextDecorations="None"
           MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter"
           MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave"
           NavigateUri="http://www.msn.com">
  My MSN
</Hyperlink>
```

I didn't test it right now, i'll do it later ;)

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey for your response.
 The problem is that most of the features what you mentioned are not there in Windows phone 8.1 like "TextDecorations" etc.