# How to remove hyperlink underline from code behind?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am parsing HTML, generating a various blocks and adding them to **RichTextBlock** control. However, when I generate a **Hyperlink** from code behind I don't know how to remove underline property. I've seen posts about creating a **HyperlinkButton** and setting its Content property but it is definitely not something that I want because I can't make it to be in line with the rest of the text and it looks awful.

Below is the relevant code for generating a hyperlink:

```
private static Inline GenerateHyperLink(HtmlNode node)
{
    Span s = new Span();
    InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();
    Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
    link.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = node.InnerText });
    link.NavigateUri = new Uri(node.Attributes["href"].Value, UriKind.Absolute);
    s.Inlines.Add(link);
    s.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " " });

    return s;
}
```

[image]

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.hyperlink):

> A Hyperlink has a class inheritance that doesn't include
>   FrameworkElement, so it doesn't have a Style property. Nor does a
>   Hyperlink have a Template (it's not a true control).

Does it mean that there is no way to achieve that using Hyperlink element?

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403999/wp-how-to-remove-underline-in-hyperlinkbutton-programmatically) with a control template?

Comment: have your HyperLink a property with name UnderlineStyle?

Comment: Yes. And as I wrote before, I don't want to use HyperlinkButton.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan UnderlineStyle is for Windows 10 devices only.